# Iterating a Json object and storing the end result

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, object, ecmascript-6

I am trying to iterate a JSON object which is an array of categories.The categories may or may not have the subcategory.

If
 `hasSubcategory = false` ,
then category id should be stored in final array.

If `hasSubcategory = true` ,it should iterate until the subcategory becomes `hasSubcategory = false` and store id in 
 final array.

There is `parentId` field to represent the parent category of the category.
More Importantly there may be sub categories for a single sub category

The final array should only be have the id of categories with `hasSubcategory = false` .

Comment: Can we see what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

`Filter` first to get the objects you need, then `map` them into the pattern you need.

```js
let arr = [{"_id":"1","name":"DESKTOP COMPUTERS","hasSubCategory":"true","parentId":"0"},{"_id":"2","name":"LAPTOP COMPUTERS","hasSubCategory":"false","parentId":"1"},{"_id":"3","name":"MONITORS","hasSubCategory":"false","parentId":"2"},{"_id":"4","name":"INPUT DEVICES","hasSubCategory":"true","parentId":"0"},{"_id":"5","name":"PRINTERS SCANNERS","hasSubCategory":"false","parentId":"4"},{"_id":"6","name":"ACCESSORIES","hasSubCategory":"false","parentId":"4"}];
    res = arr.filter(v => v.hasSubCategory === "false").map(e => Number(e._id))

console.log(res) // [ 2, 3, 5, 6 ]
```

Alternatively you can use `reduce` too:

```js
let arr = [{"_id":"1","name":"DESKTOP COMPUTERS","hasSubCategory":"true","parentId":"0"},{"_id":"2","name":"LAPTOP COMPUTERS","hasSubCategory":"false","parentId":"1"},{"_id":"3","name":"MONITORS","hasSubCategory":"false","parentId":"2"},{"_id":"4","name":"INPUT DEVICES","hasSubCategory":"true","parentId":"0"},{"_id":"5","name":"PRINTERS SCANNERS","hasSubCategory":"false","parentId":"4"},{"_id":"6","name":"ACCESSORIES","hasSubCategory":"false","parentId":"4"}];
    res = arr.reduce((a,c) => {if (c.hasSubCategory === "false") a.push(Number(c._id)); return a;}, [])

console.log(res)
```

Comment: what if a sub category has another sub category..That is id of one category is a sub category parent id ??

Comment: Can you edit your original post with a structure like that?

Comment: yes i have updated the json..you can see that last two objects have parent id 5..The id 5 object has parent id 4

Comment: The moment a category has no further subCategory is when we add it to the array, so for that the parentId doesn't matter. If there is any other criteria please define it.

Comment: @Sathyanarayanan Could you explain a bit more in detail why and how that should matter?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to chain [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) + [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) methods:

```js
const arr = [
    {
        "_id": "1",
        "name": "DESKTOP COMPUTERS",
        "hasSubCategory": "true",
        "parentId": "0"
    },
    {
        "_id": "2",
        "name": "LAPTOP COMPUTERS",
        "hasSubCategory": "false",
        "parentId": "1"
    },
    {
        "_id": "3",
        "name": "MONITORS",
        "hasSubCategory": "false",
        "parentId": "2"
    },
    {
        "_id": "4",
        "name": "INPUT DEVICES",
        "hasSubCategory": "true",
        "parentId": "0"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5",
        "name": "PRINTERS SCANNERS",
        "hasSubCategory": "false",
        "parentId": "4"
    },
    {
        "_id": "6",
        "name": "ACCESSORIES",
        "hasSubCategory": "false",
        "parentId": "4"
    },
];

const result = arr.filter(el => el.hasSubCategory === 'false').map(el => el._id);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really simple - just use `filter` to extract the items with `hasSubCategory` of `false`, then `map` out the `_id`:

```js
const arr = [{"_id":"1","name":"DESKTOP COMPUTERS","hasSubCategory":"true","parentId":"0"},{"_id":"2","name":"LAPTOP COMPUTERS","hasSubCategory":"false","parentId":"1"},{"_id":"3","name":"MONITORS","hasSubCategory":"false","parentId":"2"},{"_id":"4","name":"INPUT DEVICES","hasSubCategory":"true","parentId":"0"},{"_id":"5","name":"PRINTERS SCANNERS","hasSubCategory":"false","parentId":"4"},{"_id":"6","name":"ACCESSORIES","hasSubCategory":"false","parentId":"4"}];
const res = arr.filter(({ hasSubCategory }) => hasSubCategory == "false").map(({ _id }) => _id);
console.log(res);
```

For a more efficient solution, use `reduce`:

```js
const arr = [{"_id":"1","name":"DESKTOP COMPUTERS","hasSubCategory":"true","parentId":"0"},{"_id":"2","name":"LAPTOP COMPUTERS","hasSubCategory":"false","parentId":"1"},{"_id":"3","name":"MONITORS","hasSubCategory":"false","parentId":"2"},{"_id":"4","name":"INPUT DEVICES","hasSubCategory":"true","parentId":"0"},{"_id":"5","name":"PRINTERS SCANNERS","hasSubCategory":"false","parentId":"4"},{"_id":"6","name":"ACCESSORIES","hasSubCategory":"false","parentId":"4"}];
const res = arr.reduce((a, { hasSubCategory, _id }) => (hasSubCategory == "false" ? a.push(_id) : a, a), []);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: what if a sub category has another sub category..That is id of one category is a sub category parent id ??